# AWS cloundfront video speed loading

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have s3 bucket and cloundfront connected to it. I use afterglow player to load html5 videos from cloundfront on my website. The file has 60mb in mp4 format.  It lags few seconds after few seconds. What should I do ? Im not really specialist in AWS, there are no encoders connected.

Server-side encryption
None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are already using Cloudfront, which is getting the content as close as possible to your users. I'd suggest one of the following:

1. Create less resolutions of the same video file, which would be quick to load on slow internet connections.
2. Add those resolutions [to the player](http://docs.afterglowplayer.com/v1.1/docs/video-sources) so users can pick which resolution to stream.

OR

1. Create a Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP ([DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP)) version of the file, like: "Auto Resolution" in Youtube.com by using Amazon Elastic Transcoder to create such a file and save it on AWS S3.
2. Point AWS Cloudfront to the Amazon Elastic Transcoder destination S3 Bucket to server that file to your users.
3. Change afterglow with a HTML5 Video player that supports DASH (e.g. mediaelement.js and [others](http://videosws.praegnanz.de/)).

   This is a very helpful guide:
   [Step by step on stream DASH on S3](https://gist.github.com/askilondz/d618fb2e39f481fd19bf3f8b0476a3b6)

Comment: Thank you for answer it really helps, I hope its easier than sounds but I may be wrong

Comment: me too, but since you've already got the files closer to the users. You're only left with the option to decrease the size of the file a little. You might just re-encode it with a better encoding but keep it the same resolution. Good Luck :) Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Serving a MP4 file directly from S3 can be a problem, typically a browser will first make a GET request to know the Content-Length and then makes a lot of partial GET range requests (with 206 response) to fetch and play the MP4 file. This is a typical case of serving an MP4 file from S3.

I would suggest use Dash/HLS player, free players are available and you don't need transcoder if you can use ffmpeg.

Comment: The truth is there Will be user's videos as well, So without transcoding on aws it Will be hard